# Alternative to HTML query string

Tags: php, url

I've seen some sites use links such as: `www.example.com/r/0000` - the zeroes are the ID of the post, user, etc.

What I'm using now would be `www.example.com/view.php?id=0000`, which looks much uglier.

What's the term for the first method shown, and how would I go about implementing it to be handled by a PHP script on my site?

Comment: The first Method will be of MVC framework type , second would be custom development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These websites use `MVC` pattern (perhaps use frameworks like `Laravel`, `Slim`, etc).

Routes in Laravel:

```
Route::get('proyects/id/{id}', array('as' => 'proyects_id', function($id) {
        /* This code is executed. You can return a view or make other things */
}));
```

When I visit `www.mywebsite.com/proyects/id/3`  The route runs; you can also execute a function in the controller as follow:

```
Route::get('proyects/id/{id}', array('uses' => 'ProyectsController@makeAnything'));
```

This way you can pass information through the URL without that notation.

---

I recommend studying Laravel, it is really useful.

Laravel website: http://laravel.com/

Answer (score 0):

This in called Human Friendly URLs. You can do this by configuration your `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# if requested url does not exist redirect it to index.php
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?/ [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

All requests will be redirected on `index.php`. Then you need use pattern routingб which contains in all popular frameworks - Symfony, Laravel, Zend and other. But in its implement no big deal.

Comment: For some reason, your code didn't work for me - but after a bit of researching I got to this, which I have installed now: http://pastebin.com/Mfu45vXf - However, I'm having problems with the .php extension removal and the Human Friendly URL - if the php removal thing is active, then it breaks the Human Friendly URL. Is there any way that I can fix that?